# How to create table space in pluggable database (Oracle 12C)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When I try to connect to the pluggable to create the tablespace,I try to connect directly to the PDB as a local user with sufficient privilege, but I have this problem why?

```
SQL> $ sqlplus sys/password@localhost:1521/orcl as sysdba

SQL> $ sqlplus sys/password@localhost:1521/pdborcl as sysdba

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = pdborcl;

SQL> CONN pdb_admin@pdborcl;
Introduzca la contrase±a:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Advertencia: íYa no estß conectado a ORACLE!
```

Comment: What's unclear about: "*invalid username/password; logon denied*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> CONN pdb_admin@pdborcl;
Introduzca la contrase±a:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Either the **username** or the **password** entered is incorrect. Instead of doing it in multiple steps, directly login into the **pluggable database** using your `pdb_admin` user. Since you are connecting locally, you could just do:

```
sqlplus pdb_admin/password@pdborcl
```

Or, provide password later when prompted.

The way you are doing, should be successful if you provide correct username/password.

For example,

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@pdborcl as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Oct 23 13:31:18 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing opt
ions

SQL> conn scott@pdborcl;
Enter password:
Connected.
```